# How to concatenate two columns of different mySQL select statements?

Tags: mysql

How can I combine the following two mySQL select statements so that I get each one in different columns but same table?

```
select a.property as p1 from T1 a inner join T2 b on a.id = b.id1;

select a.property as p2 from T1 a inner join T2 b on a.id = b.id2;
```

Each of these statements work separately and will return the same number of rows. I just want to get both results in two columns, in the same table.

Answer (score 2):

Use it in a single statement like this

```
select 
     case when a.id=b.id1 then a.property end as p1,
     case when a.id=b.id2 then a.property end as p2
from 
     T1 a inner join T2 b on a.id in (b.id1,b.id2)
```

Comment: Interesting, but this did not worked... It returned many more rows than expected... Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT
    a.property AS p1, b.property AS p2
FROM
(
    SELECT a.property, @rn1:=@rn1+1 AS rn
    FROM T1 a
    INNER JOIN T2 b ON a.id = b.id1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1:=0) var_init
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.property, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rn
    FROM T1 a
    INNER JOIN T2 b ON a.id = b.id2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) var_init
) b ON a.rn = b.rn
```

---

**Edit:** Here is a variation of Madhivanan's solution which should be simpler:

```
SELECT   MAX(CASE WHEN a.id=b.id1 THEN a.property END) AS p1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.id=b.id2 THEN a.property END) AS p2
FROM     T1 a 
JOIN     T2 b ON a.id IN (b.id1,b.id2)
GROUP BY a.id
```

We're adding GROUP BY and MAX so that we don't get two rows per `id`, and we just select the maximum of the case expression which gets the non-null values for each group (essentially puts the properties in each column on the same row for each `id`).

Comment: Thank you for the second solution. Unfortunately, this did not worked as the first one: it returns rows where p1 = p2 only.